# Statement in Doctrine2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

in my repository i have

```
public function findAllMorosos($date = 'now')
{
    $datetime = new \Datetime($date);

    $stmt = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->getConnection()
        ->prepare(self::sql_morosos);

    $stmt->bindValue(':fecha', $datetime, 'datetime');
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        return $stmt;
    }

    return null;
}
```

my SQL query is

```
-- SQL
select p.* from inf_pago p
    join inf_venta v on v.id = p.venta_id
    join inf_cliente c on c.id = v.cliente_id
where p.fecha_pago < ':fecha'
and DATEDIFF(':fecha', p.fecha_pago) >= 30
and p.saldo_por_pagar != 0
```

when i execute `$repository->findAllMorosos()` i get empty array (expects 1 row), the query is fine.

when i try:

```
public function findAllMorosos($fecha = 'now')
{
    $datetime = new \Datetime($fecha);

    $stmt = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->getConnection()
        ->prepare(str_replace(':fecha', $datetime->format('Y-m-d'), self::sql_morosos));
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        return $stmt;
    }

    return null;
}
```

works fine.

can explain what is wrong with the `bindValue` method the [documentation](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/dbal/2.0/doctrine/dbal/statement.html) and [more docs](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/dbal/2.2/en/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html#dynamic-parameters-and-prepared-statements) not enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem I think is actually in your sql string. Do not wrap the parameter placeholders in quotes. And, I think you need more than one placeholder and binding. Change sql to this:

```
where p.fecha_pago < :fecha1
and DATEDIFF(:fecha2, p.fecha_pago) >= 30
```

Then, bind this way:

```
$stmt->bindValue(':fecha1', $datetime, 'datetime');
$stmt->bindValue(':fecha2', $datetime, 'datetime');
```

Note, doctrine uses it's own statement bindValue implementation which maps the third argument, if it is a string, to a PDO parameter int. Something I did not realize until today :)

Comment: what do you think of [this](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/dbal/2.2/en/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html#doctrinedbaltypes-conversion)?

Comment: yeah the problem was the quotes in the query